# How to add the new field to Object in Purescript

Tags: purescript

I am first about the Purescript.
I am going to add the new field to Object and send it as a function param.
But I can not find a good solution for this.

For example.

```
oldFiled = {
 title : "title",
 description : "d" 
}
newField = {
  time : "time"
}
//result after added new field
oldFiled = {
  title : "title",
  description : "d",
  time : "time"
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just about adding a single field you can use https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-record/2.0.1/docs/Record#v:insert like so:

```
import Data.Record as Record
import Data.Symbol (SProxy(..))
oldFiled = {
 title : "title",
 description : "d" 
}
newFiled = Record.insert (SProxy :: _ "time") "time" oldFiled
```

If you're merging records look at the merge union and disjointUnion  functions in the Data.Record module

Comment: import for v4 `import Record`